# I need youtube plug in to be be used in serviio. how to get it and install it windows7

Tags: plugins, youtube

I need youtube plug in for using in Serviio. how to get it and install it. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Serviio plugins are all groovy based. Here is a vid on how to install and configure.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tUbV_VA2cng